# Order append jQuery html is not correct, button should inside div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show html using jQuery append in this div with an id of `tablebody`:

```
<div id="TableBody">
```

But the problem is, the append button jQuery is not in order.

Here is what I have tried to append html with jQuery:

```
 $(divsrt).html("");
    for (i = content.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let obj = content[i];
        // var codeBlock = '<div class="card"> <div class="card-content">  <div class="card-body"> <div class="media">' + '<a class="media-left"  href="#">'
        // + '<img class="media-object rounded-circle"  src="https://i0.wp.com/mojok.co/terminal/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/deddy.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 64px;height: 64px;">' + '</a>'
        // + '<div class="media-body">' +
        //           '<div class="media-heading text-bold-600">' + '<a href="#">' + obj.Name + '</a>' + '</div>' + obj.Comment +
        //       '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
        // $(divsrt).append(codeBlock);

        var codeBlock = '  <div class="card">  <div class="card-content"> <div class="card-body">  <div class="media mb-4"> ' +
                        '<img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="https://i0.wp.com/mojok.co/terminal/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/deddy.jpg" style="height: 80px; width:80px" alt="">' +
                        ' <div class="media-body">' + 
                        '<a href="@Url.Action("Profile","HomeBlog",new { username = Model.Content })">' + 
                        '<h5 class="mt-0">' + obj.Name + '</h5>' +
                        ' </a> <span class="text-muted">Last Hours ago</span>' + '<p>' + obj.Comment + '</p>';
        var closing = '</div> </div> </div> </div> </div>';

        $(divsrt).append(codeBlock + closing);

        $(divsrt).find(".media-body").append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-danger").html("Delete").on("click", obj, Delete)).append("</a>")
       .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-info").html("Update").on("click", obj, Update)).append("</a>");
    }
```

This is the html that I get

```
<div id="TableBody">  
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="media mb-4">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="https://i0.wp.com/mojok.co/terminal/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/deddy.jpg" style="height: 80px; width:80px" alt="">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <a href="@Url.Action(" profile","homeblog",new="" {="" username="Model.Content" })"="">
                            <h5 class="mt-0">makkarim07@gmail.com</h5> 
                        </a>
                        <span class="text-muted">Last Hours ago</span
                        <p>213sadsADasd</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--//END .card-body //-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</a>    
</div>
```

it's not what i expected i want the update and delete button inside card but it's outside

here is what i expected

```
   <div id="TableBody">  
        <div class="card">  
            <div class="card-content"> 
                <div class="card-body"> 
                    <div class="media mb-4"> 
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="https://i0.wp.com/mojok.co/terminal/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/deddy.jpg" style="height: 80px; width:80px" alt=""> 
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <a href="@Url.Action(" profile","homeblog",new="" {="" username="Model.Content" })"="">
                                <h5 class="mt-0">makkarim07@gmail.com</h5> 
                            </a> 
                            <span class="text-muted">Last Hours ago</span>
                            <p>213sadsADasd</p>

                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</a>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--//END .card-body //-->
            </div>
        </div>  
 <div class="card">  
            <div class="card-content"> 
                <div class="card-body"> 
                    <div class="media mb-4"> 
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="https://i0.wp.com/mojok.co/terminal/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/deddy.jpg" style="height: 80px; width:80px" alt=""> 
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <a href="@Url.Action(" profile","homeblog",new="" {="" username="Model.Content" })"="">
                                <h5 class="mt-0">makkarim07@gmail.com</h5> 
                            </a> 
                            <span class="text-muted">Last Hours ago</span>
                            <p>213sadsADasd</p>

                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</a>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--//END .card-body //-->
            </div>
        </div>  
 <div class="card">  
            <div class="card-content"> 
                <div class="card-body"> 
                    <div class="media mb-4"> 
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="https://i0.wp.com/mojok.co/terminal/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/deddy.jpg" style="height: 80px; width:80px" alt=""> 
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <a href="@Url.Action(" profile","homeblog",new="" {="" username="Model.Content" })"="">
                                <h5 class="mt-0">makkarim07@gmail.com</h5> 
                            </a> 
                            <span class="text-muted">Last Hours ago</span>
                            <p>213sadsADasd</p>

                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</a>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--//END .card-body //-->
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Update and delete button inside card body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because jquery [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method always insert the new content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element. One way to resolve this would be to `.append()` the Update and delete button inside `media-body` class instead like:

```
$(divsrt).find(".media-body")
    .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-danger").html("Delete").on("click", obj, Delete)).append("</a>")
    .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-info").html("Update").on("click", obj, Update)).append("</a>");
```

instead of appending it to the `TableBody`:

```
$(divsrt).append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-danger").html("Delete").on("click", obj, Delete)).append("</a>")
    .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-info").html("Update").on("click", obj, Update)).append("</a>");
```

So, the full code would be like:

```
var codeBlock = '....'; // all current html string here
var closing = '</div> </div> </div> </div> </div>';

// You can append both opening and closing tags together
$(divsrt).append(codeBlock + closing);

$(divsrt).find(".media-body")
    .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-danger").html("Delete").on("click", obj, Delete)).append("</a>")
   .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-info").html("Update").on("click", obj, Update)).append("</a>");
```

---

**EDIT:**

We can fix the latest issue, by first creating a parent class inside the loop like:

```
let parent = `card${i}`;
```

This class will be simply used so that we can update the `.find(...)` selector to target the specific `card` inside the loop. Then we need to add the class to `codeBlock` like:

```
var codeBlock = '  <div class="card ' + parent + '">  <div class="card-content"> .... ';
```

So, `card` div will have an additional class like `card1`, `card2` and so on..

And finally, we will update the `$(divsrt).find(".media-body")` like:

```
$(divsrt).find("." + parent + " .media-body")
```

This is done so that we can add the Update and delete buttons to current `card` only, instead of all the previously added `card`s.

So, the full code would be like:

```
for (i = content.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   let obj = content[i];
   let parent = `card${i}`;

   var codeBlock = '  <div class="card ' + parent + '"> <div class="card-content"> .... ';
   var closing = '</div> </div> </div> </div> </div>';

   $(divsrt).append(codeBlock + closing);

   $(divsrt).find("." + parent + " .media-body")
      .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-danger")
         .html("Delete").on("click", obj, Delete)).append("</a>")
      .append($("<a>").addClass("btn btn-sm btn-info")
         .html("Update").on("click", obj, Update)).append("</a>");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, the button is in the card but there is  problem, if i show for 3 card it will add button became triple buttons like this https://i.imgur.com/WsSeg5K.jpg
please see my edited question, i'm using loop to show the card, every card addition the there will be button more button to be added.

Comment: I think I know what your issue could be but need more info. What is `divsrt` here? and are you adding multiple `<div class="card">` to `<div id="TableBody">` using the loop?

Comment: please see my updated questions div srt is id of tablebody

Comment: I have added an updated code with the explanation. Give it a try once.

Comment: i have tried but the button don't  show is it correct .find(parent + " .media-body")?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a `.` as it is a class: try: `.find("." + parent + " .media-body")`